# how to tell between return values from setInterval in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

The return value from setInterval in nodejs is not a number but an object. Then how can I identify which timer object is returned? The following console.log only prints [object Object].

```
  res.writeHead(200, {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
      });
  const id=setInterval(function(){

      res.write('data:helloworld! \n\n');

    }, 1000);
  console.log("to begin:interval id is "+id)

  req.on("close",function(){
    console.log("to end:interval id is "+id)
    clearInterval(id)
  })
```

Comment: `how can I identify` to what end. You store it, you use it, why do you need to "identify" it - note: change `+id` to `,id` in your console.log's to see the content of the object

Comment: You could just store the new `Timeout` object in an array and reference it that way by treating the index as an id.

Comment: Timers are objects, not integer or string Ids. You output a timer object to the console, like you output any other object `console.log(id)`, NOT `console.log("somestring"+id)`. If you want to identify a very specific ID for logging purposes, then perhaps you should put your own numeric or string property on the timer object and then output that to the console.  But, other than that, it is NOT clear at all what problem you are actually trying to solve.  Doing `"some string" + obj` in Javascript gets you `some string[object Object]`. That's what it does. It's just wrong way to look at an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're trying to do here is to identify different timers in your logging so you can correlate log messages to a particular timer, then you can put an identifiable property on each timer object and then log that id value.

```
  // variable declared at a module level scope so it persists:
  let timerCntr = 1;

  // code inside your request handler

  res.writeHead(200, {
      'Connection': 'keep-alive',
      'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
  });

  const timer = setInterval(function() {
      res.write('data:helloworld! \n\n');
  }, 1000);
  // assign ID to the timer object
  timer.myid = timerCntr++;
  console.log("to begin:interval id is " + timer.myid)

  req.on("close", function() {
      console.log("to end:interval id is " + timer.myid)
      clearInterval(timer);
  })
```